# How to load image using Tesseract LoadTiffFromMemory from WinAppDriver GetScreenshot method?

Tags: tesseract, winappdriver

I'm using the following code to capture a screenshot from a WinAppDriver session and then passing it to a Tesseract Pix class for OCR to navigate links in a table that the WinAppDriver session (Win32 app) doesn't recognize. Note session is defined using WinAppDriver's `WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Configuration;
using Tesseract;

[TestMethod]
        public void ImageTest()
        {
            String ImagePath = @"c:\temp\Image.png";

            var screen = session.GetScreenshot();
            screen.SaveAsFile(ImagePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
            Pix ImagefromFile = Pix.LoadFromFile(ImagePath);  // Works

            var screenmemory = session.GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
            Pix ImagefromMemory = Pix.LoadTiffFromMemory(screenmemory); // Fails with "IOExeception: Failed to load image from memory

        }
```

As is stated in the comments, I can save the file locally and then access it.  However, I was hoping to this via `LoadTiffFromMemory` instead.  The test fails with exception `System.IO.IOException: Failed to load image from memory`

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is most likely not of TIFF format. Can you try?

```
Pix ImagefromMemory = Pix.LoadFromMemory(screenmemory);
```

or

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
screen.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
Pix ImagefromMemory = Pix.LoadTiffFromMemory(memStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm using the  Tesseract library from Nuget ([link]https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) and 'Pix' only offers `LoadFromFile` and `LoadTiffFromMemory` methods.  For the 2nd example, GetScreenShot() doesn't offer `Save`, only `SaveAsFile`

Comment: The method is present in Tesseract 4.x version: https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/feature/321-Tesseract-4/src/Tesseract/Pix.cs

Please disregard the second one; I mistook `screen` as `Image` type.